# gvNix: Changing website alignment when language is changed

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

How can I change the alignment to the right when a language like Arabic is chosen by the user. I want the full website to be from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [Interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) to handle the logic about it and define an attribute in context. Then modify `default.jspx` and `layouts.xml` to render the page based on this attribute.

You can found [many examples about interceptor](https://www.google.es/webhp?q=spring%20interceptor%20example).

Good luck!

Comment: Could you explain more? How to do the logic and what should the attribute be? What modifications should I add to those files?

Comment: Could you help me a bit more? There is already an interceptor class for the language, I can change it with another class, but what code should I add?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is related to i18n more than related to Spring Roo or gvNIX.

Note that Spring Roo creates an Spring MVC application, then Roo and gvNIX can add some languages to that application, that is they add *messages_??.properties* to your project. To add more languages you must add them manually.

Take a look to [Spring MVC Arabic Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023465/spring-mvc-arabic-language) in order to learn how to add support for Arabic languages to your Spring MVC application.